# bat/cmd - как из переменной исключить определённое слово?

Tags: cmd, bat

Есть переменная, которая содержит путь файла с параметром, нужно убрать параметр, была попытка в For использовать delims, но он исключает не само слово, а указанные буквы. В Js есть команда split, что использовать в случаи bat?
Есть такой код:

```
@echo off
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=3*" %%I In (`Reg Query "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Classes\steam\Shell\Open\Command"^|Find /I "steam.exe"`) Do set steam=%%J
echo %steam%
pause
```

В значении steam помимо самого пути, остаётся "%1", как от него избавиться?
[image: te]

Answer (score 0):

После чтения переменной с реестра нужно извлечь все символы до двойной кавычки. Делается в 2 действия. Считываем значение в переменную **%b%**,избавлясь от кавычек по краям. Затем обрабатываем её.

```
@for /f "tokens=3* skip=2" %%i in ('@Reg Query HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Classes\steam\Shell\Open\Command') do @set b=%%~j
@for /f tokens^=1-2^ delims^=^"  %%a in ("%b%") do @echo %%a
```

Comment: А вообще-то, я бы рекомендовал использовать утилиту where для поиска пути к исполнимому файлу, если установка программы произведена корректно. Например: **where steam**